# how to call LayoutInflater object in ArrayAdpter class?

Tags: android

I have problem in Inflate method. Layout is not being loaded in ArrayAdapter class. I am new to Android Programming, please tell me how to load a Layout in Inflate method.

### Heading ## customAdapter.class

```
 package com.example.extra;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.zip.Inflater;

    import org.json.JSONException;

    import com.example.dao.StudentListDatabaseHelper;
    import com.example.dto.DriverSelectedRouteArrayList;
    import com.example.main.StudentCheckBoxAndListShow;

    import android.R;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.ContextWrapper;
    import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList>
    {

        private List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> driverSelectedRouteArrayList;
        Context context;
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<DriverSelectedRouteArrayList> driverSelectedRouteArrayList)
        {
            super(context, resource);
            this.context = context;
            this.driverSelectedRouteArrayList = driverSelectedRouteArrayList;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if(view == null)
            {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.s, root)
            }

            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


    }
```

Comment: `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` replace this within your getView() like this `return view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following code

```
if(view == null)
 {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.s, parent,false);
 }

return view;
```

Comment: in my project student_itom layout name did not call in inflate method.

Answer (score 0):

your issue is related to the fact that your are invoking the wrong super constructor. You have to possibilities. Override getCount from BaseAdapter and let it return `driverSelectedRouteArrayList.lenght()` or pass to the super `driverSelectedRouteArrayList` `super(context, resource, driverSelectedRouteArrayList);`. Also your `getView` have to return the view you inflate not the `super.getView(..)`